# Getline function in C++ is taking first input as the null character. Is it supposed to do that?

Tags: c++, getline

From the first output line it seems that it is taking a null character as the first string. Also because of this it is missing the last string it was supposed to take as input. I might be missing out on the use of getline but I'm not sure and any help would be appreciated.

```
int main() {
    short int t,i;
    cin>>t;
    string a;
    while(t–)
    {
        getline(cin,a);
        cout<<"length of string is "<<a.length()<<endl;
        for(i=0;i<a.length()/2;i+=2)
        { 
            cout<<a[i];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

INPUT

```
4
hello
understand
think
programming
```

OUTPUT

```
length of string is 0
length of string is 5
h
length of string is 10
udr
length of string is 5
t
```

Comment: After you do `cin>>t;`, the buffer still contains the newline sequence which is then later read by `getline()`.

Comment: Have a look at the related questions on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you do `cin>>t;`, the buffer still contains the newline sequence. Then `getline()` reads an immediate newline which tricks it into thinking that the user just pressed enter without typing anything.

In order to fix this, you need to ignore the newline before calling `getline()`.

Comment: You mean to consume the newline? How would you do that?

Comment: @machine_1 Look at the docs for `cin.ignore()`. I'm pretty sure this question has been answered here on Stack Overflow before. I suggest that you do some more searching now that I have explained the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `cin>>t`, it stops reading when it reaches a non-digit character, thus it is leaving the line break in `cin`'s buffer. The subsequent `std::getline()` reads that line break and returns a blank string.

So, you need to either:

- call `cin.ignore()` after calling `cin>>t` to remove that line break:

  ```
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <limits>

  int main()
  {
      short int t;

      std::cin >> t;
      std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamize>::max(), '\n'); // <-- add this!

      while (t-– > 0)
      {
          std::string a;
          std::getline(std::cin, a);
          std::cout << "length of string is " << a.length() << std::endl;
          for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < (a.length() / 2); i += 2)
          { 
              std::cout << a[i];
          }

          std::cout << std::endl;
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```
- use `std::getline()` to read `t`'s line, and then use `std::istringstream` to parse `t`'s value from that line:

  ```
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <sstream>

  int main()
  {
      short int t;
      std::string a;

      std::getline(std::cin, a);
      std::istringstream(s) >> t;

      while (t-– > 0)
      {
          std::getline(std::cin, a);
          std::cout << "length of string is " << a.length() << std::endl;
          for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < (a.length() / 2); i += 2)
          { 
              std::cout << a[i];
          }

          std::cout << std::endl;
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```